# Custom Aliases not working

Tags: config, setup

I'm trying to setup **aliases** following the [instructions in the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#control-panel-settings), but I can't get them to work (for example they don't appear when setting paths for Assets).

I copied and pasted the code exactly as the example in the docs, and the **env** variable `ROOT_URL` shows up in the CP, but the **alias** `@rootUrl` does not. Is there another step? I tried clearing caches and logging out/in, but that didn't help.

In the *config/general.php* file I pasted the code last, right below Dev environment settings. Here is that last portion of the config:

```
    // Dev environment settings
        'dev' => [
            // existing settings ...
            'backupCommand' => getenv('BACKUP_COMMAND'),
            'restoreCommand' => getenv('RESTORE_COMMAND'),
        ],

    // -- config/general.php Code example from docs --
        'aliases' => [
            '@rootUrl' => getenv('ROOT_URL'),
        ],
];
```

Also, the [3.6 upgrade documentation](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/upgrading-to-craft-3-6#deprecated-config-settings) states (emphasis mine):

> The siteName and siteUrl config settings have been deprecated. We strongly recommend you set your sites’ names and URLs using **environment variables** instead.

So, does this mean I shouldn't even be bothering with aliases? Should everything be an environment variable only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add your alias array within one of your environment array such as:

```php
<?php

return [
    // Global settings
    '*' => [
        'aliases' => [
            '@rootUrl' => getenv('ROOT_URL'),
        ],
    ],

    // Dev environment settings
    'dev' => [
        // ...
    ],

    // Staging environment settings
    'staging' => [
        // ...
    ],

    // Production environment settings
    'production' => [
        // ...
    ],
];
```